# Transparent header in webapp with data-theme b

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My *jQuery Mobile 1.3.0* application works perfectly in Safari Mobile. However, when it's run as a webapp via the home screen on iOS 6, I'm getting an annoying transparent header instead of the data-theme b I've requested:

```
<div data-role="page" id="test" data-add-back-btn="false">

        <div class="app-logo">
        <a data-direction="reverse" href="#index"><img src="/img/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <a data-rel="back" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <a href="#index" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-right jqm-home">Home</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
    <ul id="test-menu" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-filter="false">
        <li><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li><li><a href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>    </ul>
    </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" class="ui-bar">
        <div style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="http://google.ca" data-role="button" data-icon="grid">Full Site</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've attached two screen shots. One with the app run as a webapp via the home screen and displaying incorrectly, and one run in Safari Mobile displaying correctly, so you can see the behaviour. Note, I've whited out the actual text for anonymity. Has anybody come across anything like this? It's a major annoyance.

Again, this is JQuery Mobile 1.3.0. Didn't occur in early versions.

[image: Run as webapp]

[image: Run in Safari]

Comment: Are you using your own CSS somewhere?

Comment: Yes, but it only contains a few items: .app-logo, .app-logo img, .label, .labeli and .labeli span ... They shouldn't be affecting the header in any way, I wouldn't think ...

Comment: remove `class="ui-bar"` from footer. Remove all `ui` classes from your markup as they will be added dynamically by jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Removing ui-bar doesn't change how the footer displays. It still shows incorrectly, in addition to the header, as shown in the captures.

Comment: add you CSS code pls.

Comment: `.app-logo 
{
 background: transparent url("/img/background.png") repeat-x top left; 
 text-align: center;
}

.app-logo img 
{ 
 width: 175px;
}

.label 
{
 border-color:#307a00;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:1px 0;
 margin:0 .8em 0 1px;
 font-weight:normal;
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#3d9900;
 float:left;font-size:.7em;
 font-family:Verdana;
 text-shadow:0 1px 0 #333
}

.labeli
{
 border-color:#307a00;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:0 1px;
 margin:0 -1px;
 padding:.2em 0;
 overflow:hidden
}

.labeli span 
{
 padding:.2em .6em;
 font-size:100%
}`

Comment: The problem is caused by `.app-logo`. if you remove it, the header will look as it should. without logo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Bvyaj/ - with logo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LPJXU/ - notice the space above TEST header.

Comment: Thank you Omar. Am I able to put a DIV with a logo at the top of the page without creating this problem?

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, this change had no impact on how the webapp displays. The header still comes up as shown in the screen capture when launched as a webapp, even with the header removed and the code stripped out of the css file ...